# OneNote 2013: How to remember Live credentials?

Tags: microsoft-account, microsoft-onenote-2013

I've upgraded OneNote 2010 to 2013 recently and moved all my notes to SkyDrive. That's a undoubtedly wonderful option, great!

Now, I'm using OneNote 2013 in two physically different locations, both are computers with Windows 7 installed. The thing is:

- On **computer A**, OneNote 2013 remembers my Live credentials every time and it syncs OneNote automatically.
- However, on **computer B** OneNote 2013 wants me to type login/password each time I login into Windows.

The question is — how can I let OneNote (on computer B) remember my Live credentials?

Comment: The best way to resolve this problem would be to simply reinstall OneNote 2013 and verify you select the option when its offered. You likely skipped it the second time you installed it.  I updated the tags on your question to better reflect the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reinstalled Office and installed all updates to date and it helped with the problem.